# how do I test AccountsController < AbstractedResourcesController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

My app has a default controller abstracted into a gem (gem 'abstracted') and all my controllers inherits from this *abstracted* controller.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'abstracted', path: '../../gems/abstracted'

# app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb
class AccountsController < AbstractResourcesController
end
```

Now when I write controller (mini)tests for one of this controllers like this:

```
require "test_helper"

describe AccountsController do
...
```

I get this error once hitting: **rake test** from the prompt:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant AbstractResourcesController
/path_to_rails/projects/cas_server/app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

My test/test_helper.rb looks like this:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'action_controller/test_case'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'minitest-rails'
require 'minitest/pride'
# require 'miniskirt'
# require 'factories'
# require 'mocha'






class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end

class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end

class MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  # include MiniTest::ActiveRecordAssertions

  # DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  #
  # def setup
  #   DatabaseCleaner.start
  # end
  #
  # def teardown
  #   DatabaseCleaner.clean
  # end

end

class MiniTest::Spec
  include ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown

  # alias :method_name :__name__ if defined? :__name__

  def build_message(*args)
    args[1].gsub(/\?/, '%s') % args[2..-1]
  end
end


class ControllerSpec < MiniTest::Spec

  include ActionController::TestCase::Behavior
  include Devise::TestHelpers
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  # Rails 3.2 determines the controller class by matching class names that end in Test
  # This overides the #determine_default_controller_class method to allow you use Controller
  # class names in your describe argument
  # cf: https://github.com/rawongithub/minitest-rails/blob/gemspec/lib/minitest/rails/controller.rb
  def self.determine_default_controller_class(name)
    if name.match(/.*(?:^|::)(\w+Controller)/)
      $1.safe_constantize
    else
      super(name)
    end
  end

  before do
    @controller = self.class.name.match(/((.*)Controller)/)[1].constantize.new
    @routes = Rails.application.routes
  end

  subject do
    @controller
  end

end

# Functional tests = describe ***Controller
MiniTest::Spec.register_spec_type( /Controller$/, ControllerSpec )
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your controller spec file before `describe AccountsController do`,

```
module AbstractResourcesController

class Base
    def self.protect_from_forgery; end
  end
end
require 'abstract_resources_controller'
```

Comment: it's good of you to chip in <:)

- but it does not help :/  I get ```LoadError: cannot load such file -- abstract_resources_controller```

Comment: I don't know - added my gem 'abstracted' in a pristine test project and except for 3 doublerenders (which obviously has nothing with this error to do) all is good - so your 'class Base ...require...' is not necessary to run the tests -

Comment: oh no - it is I that thank you! Thank you for being there and offering your help to solving my problem! Alas the answer is - well perhaps not wrong, but, like - unapplicable, så I'd get my a** fried by the moderators, if I voted your answer - but again - thank you!